# setState being called twice, but parent function only is called once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listener, onclicklistener

So, I have this form im working on in Reactjs. I'm asking the users some personal questions for MFA implementation. But for some reason when the next button is called the setState function is called twice, even though the its parent method is only called once.

```
 NextQuestion(e) {
    console.log(e.timeStamp);

    if (this.state.answerIndex === 0) {
      this.setState({answerError: true});
      return;
    }
    if (this.state.currentQuestion >= 2) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState(state => {
      const saveQuestion = state.questionsList[state.questionIndex];
      const newQuestionList = state.questionsList;
      newQuestionList.splice(state.questionIndex, 1);
      console.log('remove');
      const newSavedQuestionsList = state.questionsToSave;
      newSavedQuestionsList.push(saveQuestion);
      return {questionsList: newQuestionList, questionsToSave: newSavedQuestionsList, currentQuestion: state.currentQuestion++};
    });
}
```

So this function is called when the user clicks the next button, it adds the selected question to the saved question list and removes it from the available ones.  however this actually calls 'setState' twice and its parent function twice

output:

```
5326.22
remove
remove
```

Im reletively new to react so im not sure if I have to clear the onClick listener whenever the component updates... but id appreciate the help;

Comment: I have no idea whether this is anyway related to your issue, but you are not using immutable state here -- `newQuestionList` is the same object as `state.questionList` and is updated in-place and pushed back to the state.

Comment: Can you please add the part of the code where the function is called?

Comment: is the only place the function is called<Button className={'btn btn-success' + (this.state.answerError && ' error-field')} id="mfaNext" style={{float: 'right'}} onClick={this.NextQuestion}>Next</Button>

Comment: Is `NextQuestion` ever bound?

Comment: yes, its bound in the constructor

Comment: I'd update it to not mutate state and see if it's still called twice. Wonky things can happen when you mutate state

Comment: @JaredGoguen i think that will work. but reguardless, its there a reason that this is called twice?

Comment: Try to comment splice and push methods and see if you have only one console.log('remove');

Comment: Another state mutation would be state.currentQuestion++ or am I seeing this wrong? Maybe state.currentQuestion + 1 should be used here

Comment: @Benjamin Yes, that's a direct mutation of state. Also, it seems unlikely that this is wanted behavior... `a = {b: 3}; c = {b: a.b++}` leads to `a => {b: 4}` and `c => {b: 3}`